# Spyder on m1 chip

Tags: python, conda, spyder, apple-m1

I am getting a new mac with m1 pro chip and want to install Python with Spyder IDE. I will be using conda to manage Python environments. I gather that as of now Spyder does not run natively on m1 chip while Python with different packages does, see for example:
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1

The question is, what is the right way to install Spyder. Suppose I'm using Miniconda, create a new environment and install Spyder:

```
conda install spyder
```

will this Spyder work correctly or crash? do I need to run it using Rosetta2? (and how do I run only Spyder IDE under Rosetta2 while having Python run natively on m1?) sorry if I am getting some terminology wrong I am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have had no issue using Spyder through Anaconda, nonetheless it will be running on Rosetta (even if you download it directly). Python will be running using M1 inside the IDE. I haven't had any major issues. If you absolutely want to run python natively on M1 then python 3.9.1 is required and you should use the console.

Comment: Good to know. So Python will be running through Rosetta just because Spyder will? And once a newer Spyder version running natively on m1 will come out and I'll update, everything should run smoothly on m1?

Comment: I've experimented on Spyder using python 3.9.13 on a conda virtual environment. And the IDE runs python natively on the ARM (M1) architecture. 
```
import platform

print(platform.processor())
```
outputs : arm

Comment: Keep in mind that the IDE itself is not native to M1 but the terminal itself runs just like any other